# How to solve this problem using linear-algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix $\bf H\in\mathbb{C}^{T\times R}$. There are $T$ transmitters and $R$ receivers with $T>R$.

Let $h_{t,r}$ denotes the ${(t,r)}$ component of $\bf H$.

Each receiver needs to choose one of the transmitters that gives $\max(\text{abs}(h_{t,r})),t=1,2,\cdots T$.

Of course, I can do it heuristically.

However, is there any way to do it using linear algebra? Does SVD or eigen value can be used to do it? Note that two receivers may end up choosing the same transmitter.

Comment: Question is incomplete

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, which the part you feel that is not completed?

Comment: "Each receiver, $r$ want to choose the transmitter such that $\max(\text{abs}(h_{t,r})),t=1,2,⋯T.$"

Comment: Are two receivers allowed to choose the same transmitter or not? If they do, is there a penalty?

Comment: @HansEngler, at this moment, two receivers are allowed to choose the same transmitter.

Comment: This problem doesn't require linear algebra. The natural solution (assign $t$ to each $r$ such that $|h_{tr}|$ is maximal) is exact and trivial to implement.

Comment: @HansEngler, I know it which I have already mentioned in my question. I just want to know whether this can be done using linear algebra.